# Responsive bootstrap rows and columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Title1:</p>
      <p>Title2:</p>
      <p>Title3:</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Value1</p>
      <p>Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2Value2 Value2 Value2</p>
      <p>Value3</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Column 3 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Title4</p>
      <p>Title5</p>
      <p>Title6</p>
      <p>Title7</p>
       <p>Title8</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Column 4 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Value4</p>
      <p>Value5</p>
      <p>Value6</p>
      <p>Value7</p>
      <p>Value8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the following bootstrap layout; it should work as the following:

Column 1 is the title for the column 2 value, and column 3 is the title of the column 4 value.

So, I have a row with four columns; the problem is that I want column 1 responsive with column 2 and column 3 with column 4. What Did I mean?

If the value of column 2 is too large, it needs multiple rows to show the result, but column 1 Title 2 does not move, so the data appears inconsistent because it is in the wrong place. Title 3 should start at the end of value 2.

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

breaking down the table into individual row solves this and keeps each row at the same height. try this

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-3">Title1:</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value1</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Title5</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-3">Title2:</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Title6</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-3">Title3:</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value3</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Title7</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-3">Title4:</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value4</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Title8</p>
    <p class="col-md-3">Value8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the same html structure you can use Javascript so get the value of the height for each `<p>` element and give them a class for its corresponding row. You can now set height of all the elements in a row to the element with the maximum height. like so:

```html
<!-- add class="row#" to each <p> element to link them to a constant in Javascript -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="row1">Title1:</p>
        <p class="row2">Title2:</p>
        <p class="row3">Title3:</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Column 2 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="row1">Value1</p>
        <p class="row2">Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2 Value2Value2 Value2 Value2</p>
        <p class="row3">Value3</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Column 3 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="row1">Title4</p>
        <p class="row2">Title5</p>
        <p class="row3">Title6</p>
        <p class="row4">Title7</p>
        <p class="row5">Title8</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Column 4 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="row1">Value4</p>
        <p class="row2">Value5</p>
        <p class="row3">Value6</p>
        <p class="row4">Value7</p>
        <p class="row5">Value8</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<script>
    const rowElements = [
    document.querySelectorAll(".row1"),
    document.querySelectorAll(".row2"),
    document.querySelectorAll(".row3"),
    document.querySelectorAll(".row4"),
    document.querySelectorAll(".row5")
  ];
  
  rowElements.forEach(row => {
    let maxHeight = 0;
    row.forEach(rowElement => {
      const rowHeight = rowElement.offsetHeight;
      maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, rowHeight);
    });
  
    row.forEach(rowElement => {
      rowElement.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: But I do not want a different order, this is creating multiple rows, I want to keep them in one row